# Amalgamation of several app.config method in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. Perhaps the question is ridiculous, but I just do not know how to do it. I have two config methods.

```
App.config(function($httpProvider) {
    // do something with $httpProvider
});
```

and

```
App.config(function($compileProvider) {
    // do something with $compileProvider
});
```

How do I use both providers into one .config method?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
App.config(function($httpProvider, $compileProvider) {
    // do something with $httpProvider and $compileProvider)
});
```